# How to compare two fields in the same table to see if they match, don't match, or both NULL in SQL with Group By?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that consists of the following:

```
Team            ID             
--              --
AB             100001
DC             100001
DC             100032
AB             100021
AB             100032
AB             100044
DC             100044
DC             100323
```

I would like to see which ID values are align per team (AB & DC both have the same ID present). There are going to be some NULLs/Mismatches due to the size of TEAM AB being 1 million and size of TEAM DC being 50k.

I tried this but doesn't have another Field ID to compare

```
SELECT Team, ID FROM Table
WHERE ID IN
(
SELECT ID FROM Table
)
```

My desired output is a new table that shows the fields 'Team' and 'ID' and the third column that shows if they matched or not.

```
AB         DC           MATCH
--         --            --
100001     100001       TRUE
100032     100032       TRUE
100044     100044       TRUE
100021     100323       FALSE
```

Comment: I don't understand how in the example `100021     100323` end up in the same row. What's the logic there?

Comment: Its just the outcome I would anticipate seeing after transposing on Team. Not every ID is a match across teams, I wanted to show that there can be unique IDs per team. If that makes sense..

Comment: So probably they would be in different rows then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want a full outer join:

```sql
with data as  (
    select 'ab' team, 100 id
    union all select 'ab', 101
    union all select 'ab', 102
    union all select 'cd', 102
    union all select 'cd', 101
    union all select 'cd', 105
)

select a.id ab, b.id cd, ifnull(a.id=b.id, false) match
from (select team, id from data where team='ab') a
full outer join (select team, id from data where team='cd') b
on a.id=b.id
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate this! This is what I was looking for - is there a reason the total row count is less than the number of rows in the table?

Comment: If all rows matched, wouldn't the row count be half?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get teams that have the same ids, then you can use `listagg()`:

```
select ids, listagg(team, ',') within group (order by team) as teams
from (select team, listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids
      from t
      group by team
     ) t
group by ids
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I got zero hits after running your code (which i checked and there are IDs that are in both teams). I appreciate the help. Anyway I could transpose the Team column and compare?

Comment: Updated desired output.

Comment: @Dinho . . . This returns teams that have exactly the same ids, which seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: You're correct, it does. Sorry for phrasing the question poorly. Thank you for helping. That is exactly right. I was just hoping to have new fields per team instead of a full list.